# How close to zNear can safely push user interface objects for a projection matrix in OpenGL 3.2

Tags: android, graphics, 3d, opengl-es, z-axis

I would like to place my user interface elements for an 3D OpenGL game as close as possible to the near clipping plane without them being cut off. For example, with this declaration

```
Matrix.frustumM(mRenderer.mProjectionMatrix, 0, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 32.0f);
```

images start rendering at a z value of -1.0, at least theoretically. In practice I find I have to place an object slightly behind this for the draw to show, and the amount depends on the user device. For example, to draw a square that fills the screen I might use:

```
final float[] squarePositionInterfaceData = {
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0078125f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0078125f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0078125f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0078125f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0078125f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0078125f
};
```

This actually draws slightly smaller as it's not quite on the near z plane of -1.0f. I find if I use -1.0 for the z placement, however, the object doesn't draw at all. I also find I have to push objects back slightly for Matrix.orthoM declarations, although with those there is no distortion as distance isn't taken into account in sizing the draw.

Is there a standard distance used to place objects as close as possible to the near z clipping plane without being cut off for the vast majority of user devices?

Comment: Are they 3D elements you expect to clip against 3D objects? If not, just disable depth testing and it doesn't matter where you put them.

Comment: Disabling depth testing does not prevent the zNear and zFar planes from cutting off rendering outside their boundaries. I did test this anyway after your suggestion to make sure.

Comment: Yes, but if you disable depth testing and use orthographic projection fir UI elements, the Z value can be anywhere between near and far. It doesn't need to be "as close as possible" to the near plane - so it completely avoids the precision problems you are worrying about.

Comment: I've found disabling depth testing does odd things to my transparent draws. Even a solid transparent color against an empty black background acquires a lighter squared maze pattern when depth testing is disabled. Nice work around idea though.

Comment: That can't be due to depth testing - there must be something else causing that.